# How to fix Attributive Error bool object has no attribute choices in python

Tags: python, boolean

I have imported the 'random module in python but when I try to use random.randint or choices, it comes up with a boolean error

```
CriticalRNG = ["Crit","Normal"]
attack = input("What attack would you like to choose? \n")
if str(attack) == attacks[2]:
    randomValue = random.randint(1,3)
    if randomValue > 1:
        print("You have succesfully stunned your opponent!")
        enemyStunned =True
    else:
        print("The attack failled!")
if str(attack) == attacks[1]:
    # this attack has critical hit of 10 damage but is normally 3 damage
    # it is weighted 1/3 critical
    critical = random.choices(CriticalRNG, weights = [1,2])
    if critical == "Normal":
        EnemyHP = EnemyHP - 3
    elif critical == "Crit":
        print("That was a critical hit!")
        EnemyHP = EnemyHP - 10
if str(attack) == attacks[0]:
    EnemyHP = EnemyHP - 5
print("Enemy has ",EnemyHP," health remaining!")
```

I expect the critical hit mechanic and the stunning mechanic to be rng, but it comes up with a boolean error

Comment: please add code and tries

Comment: My code was in there...

Answer (score 0):

You can use this example:

```
import random

print random.randint(45, 500)

list_example=['a','b','c','3','4']
print random.choice(list_example)
```

My output

> 83 c

Your answer is unclear. If you add error or add your code you would gain more information